# catkin build autocompletion

Tags: ros, catkin, build, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. This is not an urgent issue, but is quite annoying at time. So, the problem is the following. I am using the python catkin_tools instead of ordinary catkin_make in ros indigo. When I do:

```
catkin build [tab][tab]
```

I expect to have the completions of the packages currently in the workspace to pop up, but this is not happening. I am not 100% sure, but I guess I had the indended behaviour before. Instead I get

```
catkin build usage: catkin [-h] [-a] [--test-colors]
          [build | clean | config | create | init | list | profile] ...
catkin: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-color --unformatted --quiet
usage: catkin [-h] [-a] [--test-colors]
              [build | clean | config | create | init | list | profile] ...
catkin: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-color --unformatted --quiet
```

So the question is - where should I look for it? Any pointer appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213377/catkin-build-autocompletion/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-10**:
Hmm. It works for me. Not sure what I did or installed to enable it.

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2015-07-13**:
@joq, it has been working for me for quite a while too, but then I missed the moment when it stopped. So the intention behind this question is to find if somebody else had the same issue, or, at least to find somebody who just knows more than I do.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-13**:
Did you install a new version? Looks like I have 0.3.0.

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2015-07-14**:
oh, @joq, I didn't realize it has been updated. Did an upgrade - this solved the issue. I will point to your comment in a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed out in one of the comments by @joq - I have been using catking tools 0.2.0, while there has been an update to 0.3.0. After performing:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade catkin_tools
```

the issue has disappeared. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) with karma: 386 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) on 2017-03-09**:
Great! It works for me  ubuntu14.04 ROS indigo python 2.7.6

```
sudo -i
apt-get purge -y python3-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 ./get-pip.py
apt-get install python3-pip
```

then
`sudo pip install --upgrade catkin_tools`